# Save data from a form and from another component using one button

Tags: reactjs

I have an application where i can add data: age, name and if person is a man or not. Now I can get all data from inputs, but the problem is that I can't save all data after clicking on `save` button, because not all my data is from the `form` tag, some of the information I get from a table, what could be editable, and the user can also to add a new row with a new person. In this case when i click on save button, i can save only data from `form`, from `MYFORM` component, but i can't save data from `TableComponent` like : name and the info from radio buttons. So, my question is, how to save all data, clicking on `save` button, in  this object?:

```js
  const [person, setPerson] = useState({
    name: "",
    man: "",
    age: ""   //i can save only age
  });
```

link to my app: https://codesandbox.io/s/clever-paper-bsjms
 Plus, if I will have one or more persons from `TableComponent`, I want to save all of them.

Comment: The codesandbox provided is empty (initial react one)

Comment: Please provide some code; your problem can be solved with multiple ways

Comment: @MohamedELAYADI, i added the code. Probably it was an issue

Comment: @MohamedELAYADI, please, tell me if now the link is working.

Comment: I think you can keep all states in parent and update them using a callback from the child (TableComponent).